# Is it possible to update React Context from a global custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have a context set up at the highest level with

```
    <AuthNavigationContext.Provider value={AuthNavState}>
      <RootStack.Navigator
        headerMode="false"
        initialRouteName="DrawerContent"
        screenOptions={screenOptions}
        mode="modal"
      >
        <RootStack.Screen name="DrawerContent" component={DrawerNavigator} />
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="ModalAuth"
          component={AuthStackNavigator}
          options={{ cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' } }}
          mode="modal"
          initialParams={{ flow: 'modal' }}
        />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </AuthNavigationContext.Provider>
```

AuthStackNavigationContext manages all post login functions, state management for the authentication flow, etc. There are some child components which require authentication to perform certain actions. Eg. Liking a post. I want to extract the code for this state management to a custom hook that can access and write to this context. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you can use redux for that: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @CarlosDeseda the project currently does not have redux set up. Is it possible to directly modify the AuthNavState? AuthNavState internally uses useReducer

Comment: Maybe with a global state working with   userReducer and useContext. You have some examples here: https://dev.to/jackent2b/the-best-couple-usecontext-usereducer-4e65